# Еще один дурацкий вопрос о парсинге объектов в retrofit без jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, retrofit, gson

Помогите с классом pojo для парсинга ретрофитом, создавать кучу отдельных классов как делает jsonschema не хочу, хорошего туториала для ручного написания класса не нашел, всегда упираюсь в объекты в конце моего json
мой JSON https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume
заранее благодарю

Comment: Не очень понятно что именно вы хотите увидеть в ответе. Скорее всего вам надо парсить не в созданный вручную класс, но в Map, т.к. выделяемых (без нехилого количества логики) общих структур данных в JSON просто нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, при парсинге в Map я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой "expected begin_object but was string", в конце JSON где идут данные другого вида, и я не могу найти верное решение.Я перепробовал и Map в Map  и свои pojo классы для парсинга. Максимум чего я добился утыкаюсь в ошибку в конце JSON

Comment: {"TRX":"10856087.07163112","BRG":"2102133.03753825"},"totalBNB":"7.15515739","totalBTC":"968.94187536" в этом месте я всегда ловлю ошибку.

Comment: Возможно, тут вообще не получится во что-то структурированное парсить. Попробуйте просто в `Map<String, String>` парсить - такое должно сработать. И потом уже программно парсить эти строки, если они - JSON.

Comment: К сожалению не работает, отступить уже не могу и дальше продвинуться тоже.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вообще вот так: `Map<String, Object>`. Ну или даже `JsonObject `

Comment: Спасибо на object не ругается.